# Clone project from GitLab

Tags: java, gitlab

I want to subscribe(clone) repository from GitLab to my local workspace, but not all project of respective repository.
Example:-

```
InsuraceRepository
              |
              -----PNC Insurance
              |
              ------Non-PNC Insurance
```

But I want to clone only PNC insurance Project. When I use clone url it's clone both project.  I am using JGit API for cloning project from GitLab.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your clone command please?

Comment: Probably here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository

Comment: sparse checkout isn't implemented in jgit https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=383772